# Why does AWS Billing Statement show many items I never used (Free Tier ends soon)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

A year ago I played around with AWS for a bit. Today I got an email that my free tier will be expiring soon and I should take care of any resources still running.

I am instructed to look into the "Billing Management Console" and then at the last months billing statement to find out if there is anything still in use.

When I do that I get (Under "Details") 100s and 100s of lines for these Services:

- Cloudwatch
- CodeArtifact
- Data Transfer
- Key Management Services
- Secrets Manager
- Simple Notification Service
- Simple Queue Service
- Simple Storage Service

Most of the "details" are for regions I postitively NEVER EVER used (e.g. "Mumbai" or "Tokyo").

They all state that there where a handfull of requests from somewhere to somewhere (e.g. for "Data Transfer" I have a transfer from "North Virginia" to "Singapore" for "0.000001 GB" - charged as "0.00$"

This does not make any sense and I don't even have an idea what "resource" I would disable or delete to not incur any costs once my Free Tier ends.

Any AWS expert here? This is seriously stressing me out...

Comment: Are there any items that were actually charged (not $0.00)? If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, they are all zero cost charges - but I have not really a way of knowing if they are only zero cost because I was in the Free Tier until now...
I think this is really confusing.